# как в tkinter расположить кнопку одновременно наверху и слева

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Есть такой код:

```
but1.pack(side = 'top')
but2.pack(side = 'top')
but3.pack(side = 'top')
but4.pack(side = 'top')
but5.pack(side = 'top')
```

в tkinter хочу расположить кнопку одновременно наверху и слева. Но чтобы все кнопки были не в одну строку, а в один столбец, т.е. сначала первая кнопка, под ним вторая кнопка и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать grid или place https://habrahabr.ru/post/133337/

```
but1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
but2.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
but3.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
but4.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
but5.grid(row = 5, column = 1)

but1.place(x = 1, y = 10, width = 10, height = 10)
but2.place(x = 1, y = 30, width = 10, height = 10)
but3.place(x = 1, y = 40, width = 10, height = 10)
but4.place(x = 1, y = 60, width = 10, height = 10)
but5.place(x = 1, y = 80, width = 10, height = 10)
```

Так же может помочь anchor http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm

Comment: Хоть по ссылкам и есть решение вопроса, ссылки со временем могут стать битыми, поэтому лучше решение разместить в ответе